# wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, mount, hard-drive

I'm getting this error after trying to mount a flashdrive/usb partition and not sure why. I've tried different USBs for the system but all to no avail, hoping someone on here could help me figure it out.

I am trying to mount it with this comand:

> `mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt/label`

However I am yielded with this:

> mount: /mnt/label: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

Here are my block devices for more insight:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0    16G  0 part
└─sda2   8:2    0 216.8G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 894.3G  0 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   0 894.3G  0 part
sdc      8:32   0 238.5G  0 disk
├─sdc1   8:33   0    16G  0 part
└─sdc2   8:34   0 222.3G  0 part /
sdd      8:48   1   240M  0 disk
└─sdd1   8:49   1   240M  0 part
```

*sdd1* is the flashdrive I am trying to mount.

Comment: Is sdd1 a NTFS partition last used by Windows. Then in Windows you need to turn off fast startup. Or it may need chkdsk. If Linux format it may need fsck.

Comment: Are you sure there is a filesystem on that partition?  Without a filesystem, there is nothing to mount.  Use mkdosfs or mke2fs to make a fat or ext filessytem, then try the appropriate mount with the -tvfat or -text4 etc. options.

Comment: Update: found it was most likely an older kernel issue. the drive was formatted to FAT32/VFAT which should've worked, but it wasn't until I reformatted it to EXT4 where I was finally able to mount it.